# Images aren't stretched locally, but stretched when deployed? (CSS/HTML only)

Tags: html, css, image, web

I have a super simple webpage consisting of purely HTML/CSS. All works fine, as expected, when I run it locally.

However, when I deploy it (using Droppages, a static-page hosting platform through Dropbox), all of my images appear stretched.

I've tried several image sizing mechanisms -- setting image size in HTML (tried both percentages and specific pixel sizes), as well as setting image size in CSS (percentages and pixel sizes). All options work properly locally; none work once it's deployed.

Is this likely an issue with Droppages, or am I somehow sizing images wrong -- is it common for images to size properly locally and not elsewhere? Any workarounds you recommend I try? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

sounds like it could be an issue caused by droppages.

inspect the element and see what styles are being implemented, it may be ignoring all specifications and taking it from elsewhere.

have you tried a different hosting?

normally how it shows on your locahost through a browser is how it should* show when hosted remotely.